# wp media regenerate --yes --only-missing stops running

Tags: wordpress, command-line-interface, media, wp-cli

I have a WordPress media library of 80k images. A number of older images need to be resized so I'm running `wp media regenerate --yes --only-missing` which seems to run fine. When it reaches a file that needs regenerating, it does it, and then immediately stops and returns to the command line:

[image: terminal]

No errors are shown. It's running on a Linux/Serverpilot setup.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it was a memory issue.

I just increased the WP memory limit in wp-config.php.